# How do I make the center element move to the line above when lacking space?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have three elements (divs for simplicity's sake). How do I make it so that, when the space is narrowed, the center element pops up to the line above the other two? I'm using media queries right now, but the center content can change width, so it breaks.

For example with:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="Q">QWERTYUIOP</div>
    <div class="A">ASDFGHJKL0</div>
    <div class="Z">ZXCVBNM123</div>
</div>
```

When there is extra space it looks like this

```
QWERTYUIOP    ASDFGHJKL0    ZXCVBNM123
```

and when there is limited space it looks like this

```
       ASDFGHJKL0
QWERTYUIOP    ZXCVBNM123
```

Comment: If the center width is dynamic you will need javascript. Whilst this is general ordering is possible with media queries and flexbox/css-grid, there is no method of determining *when* wrapping occurs in CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this behavior using media queries. So if you want to force the last 2 elements to next line  when screen size is less than 560px, your css and html should be like this:

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.nl {
    display: none;
    width:100%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width:560px){
   .A {
       order: 1;
       flex: 0 0 100%;
       text-align: center;
    }
    .Q {
       order: 2;
    }
    .Z {
       order: 3;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="Q">QWERTYUIOP</div>
    <div class="A">ASDFGHJKL0</div>
    <div class="Z">ZXCVBNM123</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This will not give the desired result.

Comment: You can run the code snippet.  It gives the desired result as asked.

Comment: Your code does not move the div `ASDFGHJKL0` to the center and above the line.

Comment: Ohh, my bad, I misread the requirement.. let me see if I can achieve this.

Comment: I can tell you how to do this using `flex` :)

Comment: Only because you are using a specific width on your media query. since the center text is dynamic you can't use a *specific number*.

Comment: The width has to be set, since the center div has to occupy the whole space of the first row. So I guess the solution is valid.

Comment: The width of this `<div class="A">ASDFGHJKL0</div>` block may vary! Therefore, it is not acceptable to use a specific breakpoint in this task. I can make a solution with javascript, but the author didn't say that it can be used.

Comment: @MudasirZahoor, I made a decision. Check it, and you will understand what exactly the author of the question wanted.

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov your answer seems to solve the problem perfectly. Not sure if author wants a solution with JS.

Comment: @MudasirZahoor, thanks, but the author has no other choice. Since this problem cannot be solved without js.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the author is allowed to use javascript?! ...but I don't know any other solution.

The css was not shown, so I made my own rules for the main `.container`. `Flex` rules are used. Also, I don't know if the class has a `.container` specific width ?!

In my example, I used the window resize event to visualize how my code works:

```
window.onresize = function() { ... }
```

but in production it needs to be replaced with a window load event:

```
window.onload = function() { ... }
```

If this example does not suit the author, then I think that this example will be useful to others :)

```js
window.onresize = function() {

let container = document.querySelector('.container');
let Q_div = document.querySelector('.Q');
let A_div = document.querySelector('.A');
let Z_div = document.querySelector('.Z');

let sum_div = Q_div.offsetWidth + A_div.offsetWidth + Z_div.offsetWidth;

  if (container.offsetWidth <= sum_div) { 
    A_div.classList.add('class_for_A');
  } else {
    A_div.classList.remove('class_for_A');
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 500px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.A.class_for_A {
  order: 1;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="Q">QWERTYUIOP</div>
    <div class="A">ASDFGHJKL0</div>
    <div class="Z">ZXCVBNM123</div>
</div>
```

Comment: While I was hoping it would be possible with only css, I was expecting to use JavaScript. I now realize that I wasn't clear on that front and I apologize about that. This answer does what I need it to (though I think that it is possible that <= needs to be <) thank you very much.

Comment: I was hoping to do it without js, using the flex `order` rule, but I failed. Then, I realized that without js it will not work. Happy to help :)

Comment: @deef0000dragon1, Please tell me why you gave up my solution? This is a reliable solution and will solve your problem perfectly.